# connect python server and html

Tags: python, html, post, get

I created a server using python:

```
    import sys
    import BaseHTTPServer
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

    HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    ServerClass = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer

    Protocol = "HTTP/1.0"
    if sys.argv[1:]:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        port = 8008
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)
    HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
    httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
    sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
    print "Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

And then create a simple HTML form:

```
    <form action="" method="GET">
      User Name :
      <input type="text"id="username" placeholder="Enter User Name">
      Password  :
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

Using this code I want to transmit data from HTML form to Python and then just print.
I try so much but no one thread help me or else I am not capable to understand that so please give me some suggestion how to print `username` and `password` box value in console using above server code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing you need to add name attributes to the `<input>` fields on your form. Without these no data will be sent in the GET query string.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    User Name :
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter User Name">
    Password  :
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Then you should see the username and password form fields dumped to your console:

```
Serving HTTP on 127.0.0.1 port 8008 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2015 23:56:38] "GET /x.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2015 23:56:43] "GET /x.html?username=someone&password=secretstuff HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**Edit (how to handle request)**

To access the individual fields present in the query string you can override the `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET()` method and parse the query like this:

```
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import BaseHTTPServer
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

class CustomHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        query_string = urlparse(self.path).query
        fields = parse_qs(query_string) if query_string else {}
        if fields:
            print "username = {}, password = {}".format(fields.get('username')[0], fields.get('password')[0])
        return SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 8008), CustomHTTPRequestHandler).serve_forever()
```

Note though that for security reasons you should being using POST in your HTML form and https. Also, look at [CGIHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#module-CGIHTTPServer) in combination with the `cgi` module, or even 3rd party web frameworks such as [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html), [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), or even [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) depending on your requirements. These frameworks make it much easier to implement the sort of server that you seem to be after.

Comment: Note that using login forms with GET is dangerous, as the user and password will be recorded on the browser's history.

Comment: Thank you @mhawke. as you say on console both are display but i want both values username snd password in a local python valiable because i want to store in database, then what can i do

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh - see updated answer for how to capture the input field values.